# Facebook sdk compiling error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6-beta6, xcode6-beta5

What does this error mean?

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/pramonowang/Desktop/FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts,
↳   missing required architecture x86_64 in file
↳   /Users/pramonowang/Desktop/FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts (2 slices)
```

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_builtInOpenGraphObjects", referenced from:

```
  -[RPSGameViewController shareGameActivity] in RPSGameViewController.o

  -[RPSGameViewController createGameObject] in RPSGameViewController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

**clang: error**: `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have problem with Architecture. Check this:

[image]

As the normal $ARCHS_STANDARD now includes 64-bit. You can also do $(ARCHS_STANDARD) and armv7s. Just include $ARCHS_STANDARD as architecture. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: I do have the $ARCHS_STANDARD though just the same as picture. Is there any possibilities why my code error?

Comment: @user2557607 > Did you added gamekit to your project?